# calabash-android giving "No keystores found." when run under Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, calabash

I have a simple test android project that I can test fine using ".\gradlew calabashDebug" in a DOS shell logged in as myself. However, when I run the project under Jenkins on a Continuous Integration server it fails with a "No keystores found." error 
(see stack trace below).

```
07:54:04.462 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
07:54:04.464 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'cmd'.
07:54:04.507 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.ProcessParentingInitializer] An attempt to initialize for well behaving parent process finished.
07:54:04.513 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
07:54:04.513 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
07:54:04.514 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command 'cmd''
07:54:05.111 [QUIET] [system.out] No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
07:54:05.111 [QUIET] [system.out] No keystores found.
07:54:05.112 [QUIET] [system.out] Please create one or run calabash-android setup to configure calabash-android to use an existing keystore.
07:54:05.117 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
07:54:05.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
07:54:05.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':calabashDebug'
07:54:05.119 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :calabashDebug FAILED
07:54:05.120 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :calabashDebug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.666 secs.
07:54:05.120 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.014 secs, idle: 0.016 secs
07:54:05.125 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:54:05.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
07:54:05.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:54:05.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
07:54:05.129 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':calabashDebug'.
07:54:05.129 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
07:54:05.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:54:05.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
07:54:05.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':calabashDebug'.
07:54:05.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
07:54:05.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
07:54:05.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
07:54:05.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
07:54:05.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
07:54:05.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
07:54:05.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
07:54:05.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
07:54:05.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
07:54:05.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
07:54:05.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
07:54:05.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
07:54:05.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
07:54:05.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
07:54:05.137 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
07:54:05.137 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
07:54:05.137 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
07:54:05.137 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
07:54:05.138 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
07:54:05.138 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
07:54:05.138 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
07:54:05.138 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
07:54:05.139 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
07:54:05.139 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
07:54:05.139 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
07:54:05.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
07:54:05.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
07:54:05.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
07:54:05.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
07:54:05.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
07:54:05.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
07:54:05.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
07:54:05.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
07:54:05.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
07:54:05.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
07:54:05.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
07:54:05.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
07:54:05.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
07:54:05.144 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
07:54:05.144 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
07:54:05.144 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
07:54:05.144 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
07:54:05.145 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
07:54:05.145 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
07:54:05.145 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
07:54:05.145 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
07:54:05.146 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
07:54:05.146 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
07:54:05.146 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
07:54:05.147 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
07:54:05.147 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
07:54:05.147 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
07:54:05.148 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
07:54:05.148 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
07:54:05.148 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:361)
07:54:05.149 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
07:54:05.149 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.exec(Exec.java:63)
07:54:05.149 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
07:54:05.149 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
07:54:05.150 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
07:54:05.150 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
07:54:05.150 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
07:54:05.150 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
07:54:05.151 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
07:54:05.151 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
07:54:05.151 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 52 more
```

Problem is there is no indication as to where it expects the keystore to be by default. I have tried putting the keystore in a .android\debug.keystore under JENKINS_HOME directory. I have also tried to put a calabash_settings file (and also a .calabash_settings file) with the following:

```
{"keystore_location":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\.android\\debug.keystore","keystore_password":"android","keystore_alias":"androiddebugkey"}
```

I have found one issue to be that the gradle-calabash-android-plugin that I use in my build.gradle does not specify "-v" or "--verbose" to the calabash-gradle command that it spawns. I have created a fork and a pull request with a change to the gradle-calabash-android-plugin project to address this issue: github.com/Pedlar/gradle-calabash-android-plugin/pull/6

After I use the new version of gradle-calabash-android-plugin I got useful debug output:

```
15:29:02.455 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command 'cmd''
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - JDK found on PATH.
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - JDK found at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - Android SDK found at: C:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - "\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin/keytool.exe" -v -printcert -J"-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" -file "C:/Windows/Temp/d20140423-5912-102klgo/META-INF/CERT.RSA"
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - MD5 fingerprint for signing cert (C:/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Toasty/workspace/build/apk/workspace-debug-unaligned.apk): 11:FC:53:97:85:19:6C:2F:FA:AF:00:B4:DC:A1:68:1E
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - C:/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Toasty/workspace/build/apk/workspace-debug-unaligned.apk was signed with a certificate with fingerprint 11:FC:53:97:85:19:6C:2F:FA:AF:00:B4:DC:A1:68:1E
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.android/debug.keystore - no such file
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Toasty/workspace/debug.keystore - no such file
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono/ for/ Android/debug.keystore - no such file
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] 2014-04-23 15:29:03 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore - no such file
15:29:03.608 [QUIET] [system.out] No keystores found.
```

Now I am not sure why calabash-android is trying to read the keystore from "C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.android/debug.keystore" instead of "C:/Users/jenkins/.android/debug.keystore". I have jenkins running as a windows system service using the login credentials for a user named jenkins on the server.

So I added a file C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.android\debug.keystore. Still getting the same error which is odd.

I am new to developing on windows platform so it could be something as trivial as a silly white space or slash direction issue but I have not been able to figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that most of my original problem stemmed from the fact that I had installed Jenkins as a service that ran as the Local System Account (see LogOn Tab in Service Properties). This was causing Jenkins to read / write stuff in various system directories and probably running into some permission issues.

The solution was to:

1. Delete the jenkins windows service
2. Create a jenkins local account on the server
3. Login as new jenkins user and install jenkins all over again this time as jenkins user
4. When configuring jenkins sure make sure to use Service Properties / LogOn / This Account /  .\jenkins
5. Make sure to restart the service after all is done

It is the last step that I had forgotten to do in the end - Doh! Once I did that all is well!

Answer (score 0):

We found the same today with Jenkins 2.9 under Windows 10.
Gradle tries to download artifacts into \Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ , and fails.

I think this a Jenkins issue, and not Calabash related only.
The Jenkins service is installed to run as "Local System" by default. As Farrukh Najmi found out, this causes the problem.

You can later reconfigure Jenkins to run as another user.
In fact, I wonder whether you should generally do this. Jenkins as LocalSystem is considered a security issue (https://jenkins-ci.org/issue/27016).

Still, Jenkins must not be re-installed as suggested before:

### How to reconfigure Jenkins to run as User "Brian"

```
(From an Admin Terminal or Powershell)
sc.exe stop jenkins
sc.exe config "jenkins" obj= ".\Brian" password= "Brianspassword"
sc.exe start jenkins
```

...Done.
(Care for the surprising spaces after "=" in the sc.exe syntax.)

### Hints

With my first attempt, the service start failed with

> Error 1069 "The service did not start due to a logon failure."

Reason: The user may not have granted the rights to run a service, see https://serverfault.com/questions/197881/sc-exe-create-service-password-issue
This is especially the case with any fresh system User we made just for Jenkins.

Solution: My simplest solution was to run services.msc, right-click the Service in the GUI, select Properties. Modify the users password here.
Now, as a side effect, Services.msc is kind enough to grant the missing right to the user. It informs you with a popup dialog.

Another trap are special characters in the password, which need to be escaped in the shell. (I'd go with a letter-only password. Or again, type the password in the GUI of services.msc.)